# How can I add ssl certificates to AWS EKS public api server endpoint?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, microservices, kubectl, amazon-eks

I want to access the eks services through the public endpoint but when I send a request to the server my request is blocked because of **certificates not found issue**. In the browser it's still accessible after I proceed with insecure connection but when I call it from the code it's not accessible. Please help me with. I am not sure how to attach certificates with eks public endpoint.

The url is somehow like the following for **kubernetes control plane:** https://XXXXXXXXXX070EFAXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXX.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com

and I would like to add certificates with a suffix **/*** to the url like follow: https://XXXXXXXXXX070EFAXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXX.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/*

Comment: Can you explain how you installed your certificate in the cluster?

Comment: Hi @CurtEckhart thanks for reaching out. I already solved the issue, actually I had to use Route 53 to point the hosts endpoints to the DNS loadbalancer endpoint.